# How to run cucumber jvm test scenarios in parallel using Maven and courgette?

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

I am attempting to run a suite of Junit cucumber Features in Maven based on cucumber tags. I can get them to run sequentially but not in parallel. 
I found a package called Courgette that should eliminate this issue for me.

However I am unable to get the test to run I have looked at the example maven  project at [github](https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm-maven-example) It runs fine with Cucumber.class but throws an error with courgette.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have included the following in the pom

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.prashant-ramcharan</groupId>
    <artifactId>courgette-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I am invoking my runner as such.

```
import courgette.api.CourgetteOptions;
import courgette.api.CourgetteRunLevel;
import courgette.api.junit.Courgette;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Courgette.class)
@CourgetteOptions(
        threads = 1,
        runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.FEATURE,
        rerunFailedScenarios = false,
        showTestOutput = true,
        cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/Features/Online/Regression/",
        plugin={"html:target/OD.html","json:target/OD.json"
                },tags={"@Max"},
                glue="com.Online"
                ))
 public class ONLINE_Regression_RunnerTest {
}
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoaderClassFinder.loadClass(ResourceLoaderClassFinder.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoaderClassFinder.getDescendants(ResourceLoaderClassFinder.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:28)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:99)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
    at courgette.runtime.CourgetteFeatureLoader.createRuntime(CourgetteFeatureLoader.java:60)
    at courgette.runtime.CourgetteFeatureLoader.<init>(CourgetteFeatureLoader.java:30)
    at courgette.api.junit.Courgette.<init>(Courgette.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Cucumber-jvm offers parallel options as of v4.x

Comment: Thanks for this just worked that out my self now. Ah the joys of coding. So in order to get parallel test options with different browsers I can create a runner for each browser. With the cucumber tags I want to run?

Answer (score 0):

By moving the dependency to the top of my pom I was able to eliminate the conflict. 
Seemed like there was a conflict with the test ng dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There are N No of ways (mentioned below) in which parallel execution can be implemented and one of the most preferable way could be of using Cucumber starting from V 4.0.0 (Specially when we have to implement parallel execution only on multiple browsers not on multiple OS)

1. Cucumber-JVM-Parallel-Plugin
2. TestNG
3. Selenium Grid
4. Docker
5. Courgette-JVM

In Order to implement 4.0.0, please use below set of cucumber dependencies along with Maven configuration and we shall implement dependency injection as well.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Maven Surefire Configuration -

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>methods</parallel>
            <threadCount>1</threadCount>
            <reuserForks>false</reuserForks>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*RunCukeTest.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```